# Displaying a single image on a seperate page from a group of images displayed from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm so sorry that that title probably makes no sense.

Basically whats going on is I have a page with images being displayed on it that were uploaded to a database from users. I want the user to be able to select one of those images which links them to another page that only displays the image they picked. Problem is that I cant get that selected image to display on the linked page.

Any idea whats going on?

```
// Database credentials
require("config.php");



// Connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect ($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: '. mysqli_connect_error());

// Get the image
    $query = "SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                image
            WHERE
                image_id = '{$_GET['image']}' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// Back to all images
echo "<p><a href=\"images.php\">Back to the gallery</a></p>";

// Display the chosen image image
echo "{$row['image']}";
```

I'm playing with something like this, but all its giving me it a broken url path icon.

```
echo '<img src="upload/'.$row["image"].'">';
```

Comment: Check in ur upload folder if there is image

Comment: @Vicky Gonsalves images are there

Answer (score 1):

You shd echo:

```
echo "<img src=".row['image']." />";
```

Comment: Thats giving me a syntax error `syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'`